# Internal hard disk won't wipe, can't reinstall OS because not enough disk space

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, startup

My MacBook Pro 2017 (running Big Sur) is not booting. Instead, it is showing me a flashing folder with a question mark.

When I boot from an external ssd, I can see my data from my internal ssd, but I can't delete something from it.

When I'm in recovery mode, I can't reinstall the os because I don't have enough space, and in disk utility, and when I'm trying to erase my disk, it says: "A writeable disk is required (-69772)".

What can I do to erase my disk and reinstall the os ?

Comment: Can you boot in Recovery Mode (cmd+r) then from the top menu you choise Utility/Terminal then open a new terminal (cmd+n) and in this new terminal you type the command '' ``/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari``. This open a Safari windows whith you can connect here and we can exchange. In the first terminal you past the command ``diskutil list internal`` and you can add the result in your thirst message.

Comment: @Jean_JD check https://imgur.com/C5yYVeT

Comment: You have boot from external disk? You want erase the disk? Your data are saved?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want retrieve your personal datas (I suppose they are saved) you can erase the entire disk and after reinstall Mac Os X. I suppose you have an usb key or an apple installer for install your Mac os system.

I refer to this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IqWP.jpg

The command in the terminal is :

```
diskutil erasedisk apfs "Alex HD" gpt disk0
```

This will reinitialise the 128 Go SSD with an APFS Volume named **Alex HD**